# Question on the classification of Cuntz algebras via their extension groups and via their K-theory

Tags: homological-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I've recently been reading Kenneth Davidson's book on C*-algebras by example. One thing that particularly interested me was the classification of the Cuntz algebras by looking at the extensions of the compact operators $\mathcal{K}$ by $\mathcal{O}_n$. It's shown under a certain type of weak equivalence, the weak extension group of $\mathcal{O}_n$ can be computed to be $\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$, and therefore distinguishes Cuntz algebras. This approach can also be seen in a paper by Paschke and Salinas, also in a paper by Pimsner and Popa. The primary distinction here is that there is a different number of extensions that are weakly equivalent to the split extension.

As a side note at the end of the chapter, it was said that the Cuntz classified these via their K-theory. I looked into the paper, where he computes $K_0(\mathcal{O}_n)=\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$. Meanwhile $K_1$ is trivial. Here, what is crucial is the projection structure in $\mathcal{O}_n$, a seemingly very different thing.

My question is, is there some kind of relation here between the weak extension groups and the $K_0$ groups? More precisely, is there a property in the underlying C$^*$ that they both detect well?

Comment: There is a connection, encapsulated by K-homology. In topology, K-homology is the homology theory which is dual (in the Eilenberg-Steenrod sense) to topological K-theory.  Both K-theory and K-homology generalize to C*-algebras - for K-theory we usually use projection matrices as generators, and for K-homology it is possible to use extensions by compact operators as generators. So the calculation you describe in your first paragraph can be viewed as an explicit calculation of the (maybe reduced?) K-homology of the Cuntz algebra.

Comment: Moreover there is a natural pairing between K-homology and K-theory - in algebraic topology this is just the cap product. You may recall that Poincare duality, which asserts a certain isomorphism between homology and cohomology, can be expressed as a statement about the cap product. The isomorphism between K-theory and K-homology for the Cuntz algebra that you have noticed can be seen as a sort of non-commutative version of Poincare duality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, Paul, I found them very useful.